# Table cell widths altering in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, html-table, width, column-width

I have a fairly complex table which is not displaying correctly in IE. For some reason it is ignoring the cell widths and making some cells bigger/smaller than I have specified.

It works fine in Safari and Firefox.

Is this a known issue and if so is there an easy fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since IE is displaying differently it may be due to default browser styles - have you tried using a reset stylesheet?

Alternatively, if you are setting all the widths on a table manually and don't want the table to adjust itself according to it's content, you can use:

```
table {
table-layout:fixed
}
```

That's about all I can suggest without seeing more code.

Comment: I was about to give more code, but you sorted it for me already. table-layout did the trick.